# SwiftUI: apply background color to rounded rectangle

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to create a button with a rounded rectangle view with a border, and a background color.

I wrote this so far :

```
Button(action: {
}, label: {
    Text("TAP ME")
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
})
.frame(height: 50)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50, style: .continuous)
        .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)                
)
```

I tried to add `.background(Color.red)` at many different places, but here is what I get everytime:

[image]

What to do here?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As far as I understood your needs, here is a solution

[image: demo]

```
Button(action: {
}, label: {
    Text("TAP ME")
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
})
.frame(height: 50)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50, style: .continuous).fill(Color.red)
)
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50, style: .continuous)
        .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'm still not used to set something else than a color as a background...

Comment: I have a question. Your are not able to use strokeBorder and fill in the same RoundedRectangle? therefore the only way is to create an overlay?